# ftplib is timing out

Tags: python, ftplib

I'am attempting to send 5 files over to an ftp server. However, only the first 3 out of the 5 files are sent, while the last 2 are not sent.

I suspect it has to do with timing out but im not sure, as it takes around 5 minutes for the first 3 files to be transferred.

Any suggestions?

##OLD CODE

```
import subprocess

#ftp credentials
server='myserver.host.com'
user='admin@mywebsite.com'
password='mypassword'

#logging in to ftp
proc =subprocess.Popen(['ftp -p {}'.format(server)],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#sending username
proc.stdin.write(bytes(user+'\n',encoding='UTF-8'))
proc.stdin.flush()
#sending password
proc.stdin.write(bytes(password+'\n',encoding='UTF-8'))
proc.stdin.flush()

#name of ftp directory were files will be transferred
ftpdirectory='ftpdir'

#list of file directories to be transferred 
filestotransfer=['/home/user/Desktop/file1.csv','/home/user/Desktop/file2.csv','/home/user/Desktop/file3.csv','/home/user/Desktop/file4.csv','/home/user/Desktop/file5.csv']

#transferring files one by one
for i in filestotransfer:
    filename=i.split('/')[-1]
    syntaxx='put "{}" "/{}/{}"'.format(i,ftpdirectory,filename) #put /home/user/Desktop/file1.csv /ftpdir/file1.csv
    proc.stdin.write(bytes(syntaxx + '\n', encoding='UTF-8'))
    proc.stdin.flush()
```

##SOLUTION

```
import ftplib
import os.path


server = "myserver.host.com"
user = "admin@mywebsite.com"
password = "mypassword"
ftpdirectory = "/ftpdir"

filestotransfer = [
    "/home/user/Desktop/file1.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file2.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file3.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file4.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file5.csv",
]
for i in filestotransfer:
    try:
        with ftplib.FTP(server,timeout=10) as ftp:
            print('logging in')
            ftp.login(user, password)
    
    
            with open(i, "rb") as fp:
                dest_path = os.path.join(ftpdirectory, os.path.basename(i))
                ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {dest_path}", fp)
                print('completed sending {}'.format(i))
    
            ftp.close()
            
            
    except:
        print('timedout')
```

Comment: Why do you shell out to `ftp` when there's [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) as a built-in module?

Comment: not familiar with ftplib. Ill have a look at it. Is there a simple solution to the above issue? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) is a built-in module in Python.

Your script simplifies to something like

```
import ftplib
import os.path
import posixpath

server = "myserver.host.com"
user = "admin@mywebsite.com"
password = "mypassword"
ftpdirectory = "/ftpdir"
filestotransfer = [
    "/home/user/Desktop/file1.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file2.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file3.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file4.csv",
    "/home/user/Desktop/file5.csv",
]

with ftplib.FTP(server) as ftp:
    ftp.login(user, password)
    for filepath in filestotransfer:
        with open(filepath, "rb") as fp:
            dest_path = posixpath.join(ftpdirectory, os.path.basename(filepath))
            print(f"Transferring {filepath} to {dest_path}")
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {dest_path}", fp)
```

Comment: This is a better way of using ftp, however I'am facing the same issue. Last 2 files are not sent.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue with this code. How do you know they're "not sent"?

Comment: Because I'am checking the progress on the ftp server. when a file starts sending it shows up on the ftp server  and i can see the filesize increasing gradually. once the 3rd file is completed, there are no new files added. Iam trying to make a seperate login for each file based on above proposal and see if it works.

Comment: I have added revised code based on above method. Im creating a new ftp connection and closing it after sending each file (then repeating). I have tried this code, however, (refer to the #output in revised post), after checking on the server,I have completed sending 2 files only however the 2nd print statement (completed sending...) is not printed and the code doesnt continue. It seems like it might have to do with server not responding to the connection somehow. I will check with the webserver host however, if anyone has any ideas please let me know

Comment: I think this is related to the server misbehaving, not this code here.

Comment: The ftp was hanging after a file was completed. so I added a timeout on <with ftplib.FTP(server,timeout=10)> and an except statement to catch it. (see ## Solution).  Its not an optimal solution, but it will do.Thanks for your help.